# How to implement slide effect like Viber profile page in android

Tags: android, slide, viber

I want to implement an android screen where user's profile pic show half of the height and when we drag the screen downward able to see full picture and when we release again picture come in initial state(half picture). Its same like on Viber Profile page effect. Please help me give some idea how to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Someone had already  implemented such kind of ui. Here is the link for your solutions
https://github.com/MarkMjw/PullScrollView. Just clone and run the code :) give thanks to open source

Comment: +1 Nice example link, thanks.! If you have any other bookmarked links related to same feature please share,I also wanted to include zoom effect on that slide image.